# Is Kiranya a name of goddesses

Tags: name, goddess

I saw the name किरणः in some sahastranaamas of goddesses.

Is **Kiranya** the name of any goddesses in Hinduism according to scriptures?  Is it related to किरणः?

Comment: hey thats My Name :-)

Comment: @HinduKid wow....

Comment: Can you give reference to usage of the word Kiranya?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I'm thinking that it may be related to किरणः. And hence I asked.